# Cordova geolocation plugin not working on android device

Tags: cordova

I'm using cordova geolocation plugin. When I run my index.html on browser I can see my location on map. But When I run my project on android device I cant get anything. I just see white page. I'm using android version Kitkat. I get instruction from https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/index.html this link. I tried some way from another questions. But it doesnt work. How can I solve this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC-id_ZLCzQktYMWI2XrrMulXYGOzCUYhk"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
    </div>
    <script>
        var Latitude = undefined;
        var Longitude = undefined;
        // Get geo coordinates
        function getMapLocation() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
            (onMapSuccess, onMapError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
        }
        // Success callback for get geo coordinates
        var onMapSuccess = function (position) {
            Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            getMap(Latitude, Longitude);
        }
        // Get map by using coordinates
        function getMap(latitude, longitude) {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                zoom: 1,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map
            (document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
            var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLong
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
            map.setZoom(15);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        }
        // Success callback for watching your changing position
        var onMapWatchSuccess = function (position) {
            var updatedLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var updatedLongitude = position.coords.longitude;
            if (updatedLatitude != Latitude && updatedLongitude != Longitude) {
                Latitude = updatedLatitude;
                Longitude = updatedLongitude;
                getMap(updatedLatitude, updatedLongitude);
            }
        }
        // Error callback
        function onMapError(error) {
            console.log('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }
        // Watch your changing position
        function watchMapPosition() {
            return navigator.geolocation.watchPosition
            (onMapWatchSuccess, onMapError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
        }       
        getMapLocation();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>      
</body>
</html>
```

**İt is my androidmanifest.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.example.geo" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please read the documentation before coding: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/cordova/events/events.html#deviceready

Answer (score 0):

Add cordova js before googlemap api js

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

And call your function `getMapLocation();` either into `deviceReady` or `documentReady` function like

```
//deviceReady
document.addEventListener("deviceready", getMapLocation, false);


//documentReady
$(document).ready(function(){
    getMapLocation();
});
```

This will help you.

Comment: your solution is not working I already call getMapLocation function also I tried add cordova js before google maps api again didnt work.

Comment: As per your code you are not calling function after document ready that's why function not getting div created for map. So try calling function into document ready and also make sure that GPS is on in your device.